# Get back Bold Bullet that is displayed when CEdit with ES_PASSWORD MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

How to get back default **bold bullet** (**ES_PASSWORD**) that is displayed when **CEdit** with **ES_PASSWORD** is created from resource.

**What I have tried:**

```
void CDialogMain::OnBnClickedCheckShowPwd()
{
    CEdit* pEdit = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT_PASSWORD);
    if (m_CheckShowPwd.GetState() & BST_CHECKED)
    {
        pEdit->SetPasswordChar(0);
        ASSERT(!(pEdit->GetStyle() & ES_PASSWORD));
    }
    else{
        pEdit->SetPasswordChar(L'*');
        ASSERT((pEdit->GetStyle() & ES_PASSWORD));
    }
    pEdit->Invalidate(FALSE);
}
```

I want to change the **ES_PASSWORD** style of **CEdit** Control. Below code Changes it in runtime but visual look of **CEdit** is changed from **Bold Bullet** to *plain ugly looking* **asterisks**.

How to get back those *beautiful* **bold bullets** instead of **plain asterisks**

Comment: With a small bit of googling and reading I found there is an EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR message ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761653(v=vs.85).aspx ) which apparently lets you set whatever character you want. So if nothing else it seems you could forcibly set it to your desired bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the password characters back to bullets use:

```
pEdit->SetPasswordChar(9679);
```

or in hex:

```
pEdit->SetPasswordChar(0x25CF);
```

Comment: or just `pEdit->SetPasswordChar(L'●')`, Also `GetPasswordChar` returns the previous character, you can store that character when program starts...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Exactly. I used numbers because I wanted to avoid placing special characters in OP's source code.

Comment: Thank you everybody